# If two smooth paths are equivalent, does it necessary mean that they connect the same two points, or just that their traces are the same?

Tags: curves, parametrization

To better illustrate what I'm trying to say, here's an example. Path $\gamma_1(t)=(cost,-sint)$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$ is a (negatively oriented) parametrization of circle, with starting and ending point $(1,0)$, and $\gamma_2(t)=(-cost,sint), t\in[0,2\pi]$ is also (negatively oriented) parametrization of the same circle, but with starting and ending point $(-1,0)$. Traces of these two parametrizations are the same, and they also have the same orientation. But their starting and ending points are not the same, that is these paths are not "connecting the same two points". Are these two smooth paths equivalent?

(I'm looking for an answer in general, not specifically for the example I have given.)

(We defined parametrized curve as a map $\gamma:I\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ of class $C^1$, $I\in\Bbb R$ any interval. If $I=[a,b]$ (that is, $I$ is closed segment), then we also call it a smooth path. Two parametrized curves $\alpha:I\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ and $\beta:J\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ are equivalent if there exists $C^1$-diffeomorphism $\phi:I\rightarrow J$ such that $\beta=\alpha \circ\phi$ (that is, $\beta$ is reparametrization of $\alpha$). Trace is the image of a parametrized curve $\gamma$, so we also say that $\gamma$ is parametrization of its trace. Apologies for any bad translations!)

Comment: Equivalent paths must have the same start and end points, yes. That follows from the definition you stated.

Comment: @runway44 Yes, I mean the image that they trace out.  I'm trying to find the proof using the fact that two paths are equivalent if one is reparametrization of the other.

Comment: Even though many mathematical concepts have a well-agreed-on definition (or set of definitions that are shown to be equivalent), there are many places where you can choose a definition that serves your purpose (a particular theorem you want to prove, or articulate a phenomenon), and this is a good example. What do you need them to be equivalent for? At the end of the day, it's the concrete examples and theorems that count. Having a base point is convenient for fundamental group, for example.